# chmod a folder permanently

Tags: apache-2.2, django, centos5, chmod

kind of a newbie to server stuff.

I am running a centOS setup with whoosh search engine for my django app.
Everytime I restart or rebuild my index i get a warning that states `IOError: The path to your Whoosh index '/www/test/mysite_index' is not writable for the current user/group.`

How do I make sure this folder stays permanently CHMOD'd

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Chmod is already permanent.
The fact that the permissions change means that another process or user changes the permissions back behind your back.

Beside that, it's probably a better idea to use the [chown](http://www.linuxheadquarters.com/howto/basic/chown.shtml) command to change the owner of the folder.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few options:
Try looking at the umask for the user/process that creates the file.

You also want to look at the group owner of the file and the processes that are trying to read it , should they be in the same group ?

Failing that then look at adding a chmod command to a script just after the file is created as part of its creation script.

Comment: I'm sure you meant `umask`, not "unmask" :)

Comment: yes sorry , typo

Comment: you can edit your own answer ;)